# Hadoop - Sqoop from Oracle --table --columns and --where options - Date format "YYYY-MM-DD"?

Tags: oracle, date, hadoop, sqoop

We are trying to sqoop from Teradata, sql server and Oracle.
Teradata and SQLServer are accepting "YYYY-MM-DD" format for date in where clause.

Oracle where clause: 
   Where clause in sqoop command is working fine if we give date format in "dd-Mon-yyyy" format.

Question:
   Is there any way we can set some connection parameter or some paramer to specify date will be in "YYYY-MM-DD" format instead of "DD-MON-YYYY" format?

Or is there any "java command line parameters" which can be passed to enable "YYYY-MM-DD" format?

We are trying it using Hadoop Sqoop which uses JDBC Thin driver.
So, NLS_DATE_FORMAT option is ruled out.

Which locale/NLS_TERRITORY supports YYYY-MM-DD format?

We need this because we want to use generic code across different db and modules. Otherwise we have to customize the code to add another format as well.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you invoking the sqoop command?

Comment: Generic oozie workflow with "sqoop" action which has <arg> tags for all sqoop arguments like <arg>--columns </arg> <arg> col1, col2, etc</arg> <arg>--table</arg>    <arg>--where</arg> <arg> where datecol between ${startdate} and ${enddate}</arg>